# Android: cannot run app on connected phone, using Ubuntu in VM in Windows 7

Tags: android, debugging, ubuntu

I'm trying to develop an Android app. I'm developing in Eclipse which is running in an Ubuntu VM hosted on Windows 7.

I can run the app in the emulator just fine. However, if I connect my phone to the PC via USB, when I run the app I don't see it listed in Android Device Chooser.

I have followed the instructions in http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html. Running

```
adb devices
```

...shows an empty list of devices. Ubuntu just doesn't know it's there.

I wonder if it's because I'm running ultimately on Windows. When I plug the phone in, Windows responds to it, so it's not like there's no driver installed. If Windows knows it's there, does that mean it's somehow 'hidden' from the VM?

Can anyone help me diagnose the problem?

The phone is a Galaxy SII by the way. I hear they're pretty tricky to debug on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What virtual machine application are you using?

If you are in VirtualBox, VMWare, or the like, you will need to use the USB icon (usually lower right of the VM window), and connect the device virtually into the virtual machine.

Then, you can debug.

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox. I've managed to add a 'Device Filter' in the USB category. But I'm not sure what I'm expecting to see in the Ubuntu VM. I'm new to Linux too. :) Where would I find the USB in File Manager?

Comment: Wait a minute... adb devices now gives me something. I'm firing up Eclipse now...

Comment: I don't think it had anything to do with device filters at all... I found the little USB icon eventually. I've got the app running on my phone. Thank you, you have made a stranger many thousands of miles away very happy. :)